# Can't connect to MSSQL from PHP

Tags: php, database

I have been trying to connect to my SQL server from my web host using the built-in PHP functions, but no luck so far.

This is my code:

`mssql_connect("201.252.95.27:1433/SQLEXPRESS", $sqlServerUsername, $sqlServerpassword);`

And this is the error:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server

Tried using "201.252.95.27", "201.252.95.27:1433", "201.252.95.27,1433", "201.252.95.27:1433/SQLEXPRESS" and all possible combinations, but it isn't working.

The server is running and the port is open.

Comment: Are you using a SQL Server user or Windows Domain user? You may want to look into [`sqlsrv_`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) functions.

Comment: SQL Server instances usually use a backslash, and a comma to separate port: 201.252.95.27,1433\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: @njk I think a Windows Domain user

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server usually uses a comma to separate the port, and a backslash to separate the instance name.

Using `201.252.95.27,1433\SQLEXPRESS` I was able to connect to your server, but lacking a username/password, I couldnt log in.

Comment: user:sa, pass:p4ssw0rd. No one will ever figure it out.

Comment: I still can't connect. Are you using mssql_connect()?